# c# application setting not saved

Tags: c#, app-config

Using **VS2010 Express**, **Win7-64.**
In my application I Have several Application settings.
Most (mixed types) are User Settings, one is Application Setting (a DataSet).

I use the built-in Settings table where the one setting scope is set as Application, while the others scope is User.
The User settings are all saved and retrieved OK, and can also be seen in the XML file.

```
(string userConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                  ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath;)
```

**Problem:** While the User settings are saved OK, the one Application Setting is not saved and is not present in the relevant config file.

```
(string appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                  ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;).
```

In the `Settings.Design` file we can see the Application Setting as read-only item (get only), which is OK, but no data is saved, and no data is found, (except a null DataSet).

There is similar DataSet in the User settings that is saved OK, and can be loaded.

To save the settings, I run:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Thanks

Comment: @PatrickHofman that is good practice, otherwise whenever a new version of the software is run, it will create an entirely new copy of settings with default values. But it should be done BEFORE loading.

Answer (score 0):

Application-scope settings are read only, and can only be changed at design time.
so when you call save method it does not persist the data.

User-scope settings, however, can be written at run time, just as you would change any property value.

for more information you can see [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: PatrickHofman: As I wrote, the data is not saved to the XML file, thus update has no affect anyhow.
To Lamourou: Thanks, but, as you wrote, the Application setting can only be updated at design time, and this is exactly what I do.
How else can the app setting be saved initially?
Did I miss anything?